# how to access db from node.js middleware

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, middleware

I want to verify that a user has a role which allows him/her to use an endpoint in my API. Usually I would go about doing so by taking the userId sent as part of a JWT and do a lookup on the DB to see what the user's role is. It would happen inside an API call and would look something like this:

```
var userId = getUserIdFromJwt();

app.models.User.findOne({_id: userId}, function (err, user) {
    ...check if user is in role...
});
```

Now I want to try and move that code to a piece of middleware, which would look like this:

```
exports.isUserInRole = function(app, allowableRoles) {
    var userId = getUserIdFromJwt();

    app.models.User.findOne({_id: userId}, function (error, user) {
        if (error) {
            return res.status(500).json(error);
        }

        return function (req, res, next) {
            if(_.includes(allowableRoles, user.Role)) {
                next();
            } else {
                return res.status(401).json({"error": "User not in role"});
            }
        }
    });
};
```

The middleware would be implemented like this:

```
const allowableRoles = ['admin', 'implementor'];
app.get('/getStuff/', isUserInRole(app, allowableRoles), function (req, res) {
   ... do stuff if user is in role ...
});
```

At this point I am running into a problem where the `app.models.User` value  is always `undefined`.

I do not understand why `app.models.User` is undefined at this point as I can access it within the anonymous function inside the get call.

How would I go about about access the DB from within my middleware if I cannot send it `app.models.User`?

For reference, I am using Mongoose and exposing it to my app in the server.js from which I access the a MongoDB db.

Comment: So that I understand it correctly, is `app.models.User` undefined in the function that is being called after the `isUserInRole` or during?

Comment: i.e. is `app.models.User.findOne` undefined?

Comment: `app.models.User` is undefined at the moment when `isUserInRole` is called as middleware, but it is available in the next function. For example, if I take `isUserInRole` out as middleware and call it as a normal function within the anonymous function, then I can see that a call to the db is made because `app.models.User` is not undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're problem is that you are trying to get models before they are actually initialized, as you are binding the app to the parameters on initialization of the app.

So in your main app file, I would do `module.exports = app;` and then in your middleware file, simply include the app by doing `var app = require('./path/to/app');`. Then remove the `app` from the middleware. You might end up with something like this:

```
var app = require('./path/to/app');

exports.isUserInRole = function(allowableRoles) {};
```

And in your route change it to this:

```
const allowableRoles = ['admin', 'implementor'];
app.get('/getStuff/', isUserInRole(allowableRoles), function (req, res) {}
```

And lastly in your app file, add the app to the exports:

```
module.exports = app;
```

EDIT:

If you're using Mongoose, you can also do something more simple like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = mongoose.model('User');
```

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be b/c you are actually calling the function instead of just passing it in. Additionally, you're not actually passing in middleware. Middleware functions look like

```
function(req,res,next){}
```

Additionally, you probably want to leverage sessions instead of hitting the database on each request

Comment: I don't think using sessions are necessarily the right way to go. I would prefer keeping the API stateless. This is why I chose to use JWT. I could add the user's role to the JWT payload, but I feel this is unsafe as I cannot trust anything the user sends back - unless I use ssl, which I do not want to do during development. Not trusting the user is why I need to check what privileges he/she has in order to decide to continue or not and a simple db call isn't too expensive, is it? (I should make it less expensive by specifying the columns to return and not return all as I have now.)

Comment: @MrThursday you can still use sessions and still keep your backend stateless. You're  right, you shouldn't accept permissions from the client, that's really bad. However, you could do your db call once and then store their permissions in a server side session variable so you don't have to hit the db on the next request. Obviously you'd have to manage the session, including handling situations when a user's roles are modified.  That's beside the point though, I think your real issue is that your not actually writing your authorization call as middleware.